# Whats meaning of the under wave green line in my file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

The under wave green line in my code(under the `/userfiles/`):

[image]

The code is below:

```
<baseDir></baseDir>
<baseURL>/userfiles/</baseURL>
<licenseKey></licenseKey>
<licenseName></licenseName>
```

I don't know why there is the wave line under my code, if is somewhere I get mistake?

Comment: No, It is not an error, It just a hint you can click on It to see the hint

Comment: You could easily answer that yourself when you dare to hower your mouse above the underlined word ...

Answer (score 1):

That means the IntelliJ IDEA check your word if is correct spelling.

If you change the `userfiles` to `file` or `user`, it will not have the under wave line, so there is no problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

When something is underlined in IntelliJ you should press Alt + Enter, it will show you either if something is wrong or how it can be improved. But yes as mentioned before when it is green it means it is spelled correctly

Answer (score 0):

It intellij spell checking activated there, according to the standard dictionary of words stored.

Comment: it is more like user hint , to get your attention.